# Playing MPEG files?

Tags: video

I have a number of `352x288x25` fps `MPEG-1` files (that is, the contents of PAL VCD discs). How can I get these to play smoothly on the Pi?  I have tried omxplayer, but it just says "have a nice day" rather than actually playing anything. I have also tried installing VLC, but that only manages about 1 fps.

Is there some other way of playing these I can use? Will the MPEG-2 license help, or is there a more efficient player available? I used to play these on a 266 MHz Pentium 2 without hardware acceleration, so I'm not sure why I'd need acceleration on a 700 MHz ARM, which is at least theoretically faster.

Comment: It's weird that these don't play back in vlc. Can you confirm that they're stable on a known-good machine other than the pi?

Comment: I agree with @goobering. Without hardware encoding, VLC won't be the fastest thing on the RPi, but I would expect it to perform better than 1 fps.

Comment: The videos play fine on a PC. Not sure what the issue is, but other than hardware accelerated videos via omxplayer I don't seem to be able to get anything to play at a reasonable frame rate.

Comment: What's your memory split?

Comment: @goobering I have 64MB GPU memory.

Comment: My best suggestion would be to set that to 256MB and try again. If it works, half it to 128MB and repeat until it doesn't.